# Amazon SageMaker Ground Truth Custom Labeling Jobs Error: Cannot read property 'taskInput' of null

Tags: label, amazon-sagemaker

When creating a custom labeling job for Amazon SageMaker Ground Truth Custom 
Am getting the following error:

`Cannot read property 'taskInput' of null`

Answer (score 2):

> The pre-annotation AWS Lambda function should provide an object named `taskInput` and that object's properties can be accessed as {{ task.input. }} in your template. 
>   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sms-custom-templates-step2-demo1.html

so in your pre-annotation lambda function you need to make sure to forward the `taskInput`; e.g.:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    return {
        "taskInput": event['dataObject']
    }    
};
```